# Where do i start with game development when i'm terrible at art and 3d modelling?

Tags: game-design, textures, software-engineering, art, 3d-modeling

I've wanted to try and make my own game for a while now but i'm i'm terrible at art, textures and 3D modelling but i want to learn it so has anyone got any pointers to get started with the whole shebang?

Comment: Try asking this on gamedev.net it'll just be flagged as off topic here.

Comment: Agreed, but I really wanna know too...

Comment: google tutorials for the stuff you want. Try stuff, experiment, dedicate a couple of hours a day to this stuff and bingo bango bosh you've learned some basics. It's really this simple.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do exactly? I mean, do you share any quality or have any qualification to do something in particular? For example i'm terrible at modeling and art but i'm not bad programming, then i'm focused on 3D engines(collisions, rendering, optimizations, algorithms...). The thing is to find what you are good at and you enjoy.

If you want to learn about my area i can easily give you a lot of information and recommendations.

Comment: You should avoid answering off-topic questions.

Comment: I can't use the "add comment" yet in this stack community, and i needed some more information about what he demands. If he wants to learn about programming i can surely help him.

Comment: Still, if you answer off-topic questions you encourage people to ask more off-topic questions.

Comment: Ok i understand, won't do it again.